# ¿Cómo hacer para que el programa no llegue al mínimo que le estoy indicando? C#

Tags: c#

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que quiero hacer es decirle al programa qué me de los múltiplos de 5 menores que 10 SIN llegar al mismo 10 y no entiendo la razón por la cúal cuando ejecuto el código el programa me presenta el 5 y el 10.

Aquí les abjunto el código y espero que me puedan colaborar, si ven la imagen verán que la consola me imprime el 10 cuando yo quiero que me imprima los múltiplos MENORES que 10 sin llegar al 10 mismo, lo cual significa que solo debería presentar el 5, espero que me puedan ayudar y gracias de antemano.

```
 int multi2 = 0;
 for (int multiplo2 = 0; multiplo2 < 10; multiplo2++)
 {
     multi2++;
     Console.WriteLine(multiplo2 = num2 * multi2);
 }
```

Comment: Me pregunto por qué en lugar de complicarse no solo usan la variable `multiplo2`, en la sección de incremento `multiplo2 += 5` y en el `WriteLine()` solo pasan la variable

Comment: Hola Ricardo, podrías decir si las respuestas te fueron útiles, y marcar como aceptada la que mejor consideres, y si lo deseas también darles un voto, gracias

Answer (score 3):

Una manera mucho mas sencilla de hacerlo seria un ciclo que vaya de 1 a 9 y con tu variable que te está iterando ese rango de 1 a 9 verificas sí es múltiplo de 5, si es asi pues lo imprimes.

Ejemplo:

```
for (int multiplo2 = 1; multiplo2 <= 9; multiplo2++)
    {
       if (multiplo2 % 5 == 0)
       {
          Console.WriteLine(multiplo2);
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Repasemos tu código:

```
//Creo que faltaría una variable entera que sería:
int num2 = 5;
//creas variable multi2 que igualas a cero
int multi2 = 0;

//ahora programas un bucle for usando la variable de iteracion multiplo2
for (int multiplo2 = 0; multiplo2 < 10; multiplo2++)
{
    //sumas uno a la variable multi2
    multi2++;
    
    Console.WriteLine(multiplo2 = num2 * multi2);
}
```

En la primera iteración multiplo2 vale cero, como es menor que 10 realiza el código que sale por consola y muestra multiplo2 que es igual a num2 (5) por multi2 (1), y por eso imprime 5

En la segunda iteración, multiplo2, ahora vale 5, y le sumamos 1 según el bucle for, como 6 es menor que 10, entra de nuevo en el código que inluye el bucle y realiza de nuevo la operación mostrando:

multiplo2 que es igual a num2 (5) por multi2, que valía 1 y ahora al sumarle uno más, vale 2, por lo tanto te imprime 10

Creo que tu planteamiento no es del todo correcto, verás, te pongo el código que te dirá los múltiplos de un número introducido por teclado que el mismo programa te pide

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //pedimos el número del que deseamos sus múltiplos
        Console.WriteLine("Inserte el número del que desea conocer sus múltiplos:");
        //tomamos el número y lo convertimos en entero
        int multiplos = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        //escribimos la frase con el número dado
        Console.WriteLine("Los multiplos de " + multiplos + " son");
        //hacemos un for con tope del número
        for (int x = 1; x < multiplos; x++)
        {
            //llamamos al método enviando el número por parámetro y la variable del bucle, si recibimos un true, o sea, si es múltiplo
            if (esMultiplo(multiplos, x))
            {
                //escribimos en pantalla un espacio y el número
                Console.WriteLine(" " + x);
            }
        }
    }
    //método que nos dice si es o no es múltiplo que recibe el número1 del que deseamos saber si el número2 es múltiplo
    public static Boolean esMultiplo(int numero1, int numero2)
    {
        //si el resto de dividir el segundo número entre el primero es cero
        if (numero1 % numero2 == 0)
        {
            //devuelve true
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            //si no es cero, devuelve false
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar **Linq**:

```
var multiplos5 = (from n in Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
                  where n < 10 && n % 5 == 0
                  select n).ToList();
```

Aquí generamos un rango con números desde **1** hasta **10** y filtramos los números que son menores a **10** y múltiplos de **5**, devolviendo una lista con los números que cumplen estas condiciones.

Para imprimir esta lista harías:

```
foreach(n in multiplos5)
{
   Console.WriteLine(n.ToString());
}
```

Usamos un **foreach** que recorrerá la lista de números obtenidos múltiplos de **5** y los imprimirá en la pantalla.

Para usar **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```